# Can I execute commands silently in gdb?

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to execute a command silently so that it doesn't print feedback (such as `Breakpoint 1 at 0x5c4` after setting a breakpoint)? Such a feature would be especially useful for me for a scripted debugging session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<1000;i++) {
     printf("%d\n", i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

inside gdb

```
(gdb) break 6
(gdb) commands
(gdb) silent
(gdb) end
```

Alternatively, if you want to skip few initial breakpoints

```
ignore 1 999
```